# Is India's purchase of Russian weapons a strategy or necessity?

Tags: russian-federation, military, india

I know that India has been a traditional customer of Russian weapons. However, they have almost all the options open, like, American, European, Korean, Japanese, Singaporean, etc.

Why does India continue to purchase Russian weapons given the risk of American sanctions?

Is it a necessity or is it to keep Russia diplomatically engaged?

Is India's purchase of Russian weapons a strategy or necessity?

Comment: Please don't use comments to guess what the answer *could* be. If you would like to answer, then please do some research and post a real answer which measures up to our quality standards.

Comment: Right now you seem to be asking for speculation and motivations. Please [edit] your question so that this is no longer the case.

Answer (score 3):

It's complicated.  First, I don't follow your initial claim:

> given the risk of American sanctions

If you are referring to Turkey's S-400/F35 conundrums, this was a bit of a special case.  Turkey was a full-on participant in the F35 program and was supposed to be the main European-area maintenance country for them.  For example, the UK could not perform deep servicing on F35s and would have had to [send them to Turkey](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-39501299).

With Erdogan flirting with totalitarianism/religious fundamentalism **and** Russia, NATO wanted to uncouple the F35 program from Turkey.  Not to deny, of course, that the US can play hardball to further its commercial interests.

If you are referring to [Countering America's Adversaries Through Sanctions Act (CAATSA)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countering_America%27s_Adversaries_Through_Sanctions_Act) it a) is a Trump-era law, b) seems geared against Russia, Iran and North Korea and c) allows POTUS to elect *not* to impose sanctions:

> The President may temporarily waive the imposition or continuation of sanctions under specified circumstances.

All the above to say that the claim that the US would impose sanctions on India for buying Russian weapons needs a lot more sourcing.  India is not easily comparable in this context.

> American, European, Korean, Japanese, Singaporean

Japan, Korea, Singapore... etc... are **not** tier 1 weapon suppliers so buying from them, as opposed to Russia, makes little military sense.  India has been buying more gear from Israel which makes sense, as long as it keeps an eye on [Israel->China military sales](https://www.trtworld.com/magazine/israel-s-suicide-drone-sales-to-china-puts-tel-aviv-in-awkward-bind-with-us-44632).

Traditionally, India buys weapons from Russia and France.  Once you have weapons from one block, there is a strong incentive to continue in that direction, *because various weapon systems function best when tightly integrated together*.

Suddenly bringing say American systems in an air defense/air superiority context would complicate having that hardware "talk to" the existing [Indian assets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Air_Force#Aircraft_inventory) which are **not** American.

For example, one argument on the US side to promote the F35/F18 replacement for the new Canadian fighter is that choosing the Swedish Grippen will create an integration problem.  That's [not in fact the case](http://www.canadiandefencereview.com/Featured_content?blog/182), but it still gets bandied around:

> Many in Canada, and in fact North America, are unaware that Gripen fighter jets have already integrated seamlessly with NATO and allied forces. For example, Gripens of the Swedish Air Force integrated seamlessly into coalition operations during the United Nations air campaign over Libya.

So given that India has a history of buying from Russia, it is not obvious why it has any real **military** reason to stop doing so.  Russian weapon systems are not laggards in any sense and are likely cheaper than some US alternatives.

At a political level, India is probably trying its best to keep Russia from becoming more chummy with China so [keeping close defense ties](https://www.cnn.com/2021/12/06/india/india-russia-arms-deal-putin-modi-intl-hnk/index.html) makes perfect sense.

Buying from the US does not reinforce *India+US-vs-China* near as much, since the US is already perfectly capable of aligning itself against China on its own.

Conversely, the US is very much interested in keeping India on its side vs China and is therefore unlikely to impose sanctions.

Comment: SAAB tried to sell Viggen to India in the 70s.  The US government could due to the engine say no.  France/Russia/China/UK isn't dependant on an US license for selling fighter jets.